# In Microsoft Access allow tagging from a table to a record

Tags: ms-access

I have a simple database that I am using to track quotations. Each field in the main table is "Source", "Quotation", "Reference".

I want to add a fourth field (fifth if you count the key field) that will function like the "tags" utility on StackOverflow, so that if the quote talks about China and geography, the field will have two values: "china" and "geography". I would like that field to refer to a different table which will contain all of the tags, and ideally I would be able to add tags to the table without leaving the main table.

I have already created the database, and can either have a single tag, or link to a list of tags, but I cannot get it to work as described. This has to be something that is a common function, since tags are common in programming and databases, but the only things that I can find are about "smart tags" which have to do with the values of fields, and are not at all what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add tag entries as their own table. So you will have:

```
**tblQuotations**
QuotationID
Source
Quotation
Reference

**tbltags**
TagID
TagDescription

**tblTagEntries**
TagEntryID
QuotationID
TagID
```

Comment: Will this allow me to add new tags from "tbleQuotations"? If not, what do i need to do?

Comment: There is no `tags` functionality the way you want it in databases. You have to make it. To add a tag you insert a record in the `tblTagEntries` table using the ID of the Quotation and the ID of the Tag you want to add. To access the tags of a specific Quotation you query `tblTagEntries` looking for the ID of the Quotation.